# Red-Black tree simple application

Tags: tree

I have an assignment to implement the red-black tree and do do a task with it which is invented by me. can you help me out with some simple ideas where I can use red-black trees to solve a problem? It doesn't have to be a complicated problem, it just needs to be solvable with the help of the red black trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red-black tree is widely used as an abstract data structure. You can use it in a variety of situations. 
Most basic ones I can think of include ordering a deck of cards, where everycard holds it's unique ID.

Comment: thats a good ideea but i need to give every card a ID , you said the basic ones include this so can you tell me maybe another?